# Django Media URL not returning string to Media folder

Tags: django, media

Running django 2.0 in development and I am trying to display user uploaded images in a List view.

Here is the line for the img tag

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{MEDIA_URL }}{{ selected_membership.image }}" alt="Subscription Logo">
```

For testing purposes {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ selected_membership.image }} returns "my_image.jpg". So clearly the MEDIA_URL is not working, but the second part is.

**Urls.py**

```
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Settings.py**

```
...
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

{{ MEDIA_URL }} Needs to return /media/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django model (`ImageField`) support calling url for your image. You don't have to use `MEDIA_URL`. Just using `{{ selected_membership.image.url }}` instead.

It will give your image path and name.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not provide MEDIA_URL keyword to templates. It uses in models for serve files that saved through the model field such as FileField or ImageField. If you sure that you need MEDIA_URL keyword in your templates you can implement it as context variable. For example:

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'example/template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['MEDIA_URL'] = 'your_media_url'
        return context
```

If you need this url for model field's file you can simply write in your template something like:

```
{{ model_name.field_name.url }}
```